# How to find-and-replace specific string in a file?

Tags: r, replace, gsub

I have data like this:

```
Ind M1  M2  M3  M4  M5
P1  A/A Unused  G/A T/T T/T
P2  T/T A/A A/A A/A G/G
1   T/A A/A G/A T/T G/G
2   Unused1 A/A G/A T/T T/G
3   T/T A/A G/A T/T T/G
4   Unused1 A/A G/A A/T G/G
5   T/A A/A G/A A/T Unused1
```

and I want to replace `T/T` with `TT` in a whole file. 
Please find link to my data here

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r1eib3grr11tjpw/data.txt?dl=0

I used gsub function, but what I am getting is strange output, like
 `"c(6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)" "c(1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2)" "c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)`

How to replace this `T/T` with `TT`?

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried with `gsub` so far?

Comment: tx  <-read.table("data.txt",header=T,sep="")
tx2  <- gsub(pattern = "T/T", replace = "TT", x = tx)

Answer (score 1):

Data:

```
df1 <- read.table(text="Ind M1  M2  M3  M4  M5
P1  A/A Unused  G/A T/T T/T
                  P2  T/T A/A A/A A/A G/G
                  1   T/A A/A G/A T/T G/G
                  2   Unused1 A/A G/A T/T T/G
                  3   T/T A/A G/A T/T T/G
                  4   Unused1 A/A G/A A/T G/G
                  5   T/A A/A G/A A/T Unused1", header = TRUE)
```

code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(lapply( df1, function(x) gsub("T/T", "TT", x, fixed = TRUE)))
df1
#   Ind      M1     M2  M3  M4      M5
# 1  P1     A/A Unused G/A  TT      TT
# 2  P2      TT    A/A A/A A/A     G/G
# 3   1     T/A    A/A G/A  TT     G/G
# 4   2 Unused1    A/A G/A  TT     T/G
# 5   3      TT    A/A G/A  TT     T/G
# 6   4 Unused1    A/A G/A A/T     G/G
# 7   5     T/A    A/A G/A A/T Unused1
```

To replace all the `"/"` with `""`, use:

```
data.frame(lapply(df1, function(x) gsub("/", "", x, fixed = TRUE)))
```

Comment: @zx8754: OP wants to work on only "T/T". I think your edit to my solution may be incorrect, because it replaces "/" globally.

Comment: I added as an extra option. The data is genotypes, and it only makes sense to keep all genotypes as "A/B" or "AB", not mixed, pretty sure that is what OP wants to achieve, but feel free to rollback the edit.

Comment: @zx8754 : I am ok with your edits. Is there a genotype called "Unused1" :).

Comment: I am assuming "Unused1" means "NoCall", it can be coded in many ways. "0/0", "-/-", etc.

Comment: I agree with your suggestions. I think the genotype calling may be done using a non-standard way unlike in Illumina platform.

Answer (score 0):

Using base `R` you can do something like that (supposing your data is called `your_data`):

```
as.data.frame(sapply(your_data, function(x) gsub("T/T", "TT", x)))

#  Ind      M1     M2  M3  M4      M5
#1  P1     A/A Unused G/A  TT      TT
#2  P2      TT    A/A A/A A/A     G/G
#3   1     T/A    A/A G/A  TT     G/G
#4   2 Unused1    A/A G/A  TT     T/G
#5   3      TT    A/A G/A  TT     T/G
#6   4 Unused1    A/A G/A A/T     G/G
#7   5     T/A    A/A G/A A/T Unused1
```

Comment: Thank you very much patl, zx8754 and sathish for your valuable work and code worked perfectly